# "Is" or "are"? What is the corret form here?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

In the sentence below which one is correct to use?

Little things like that **are** what will make your life together worth living.

Little things like that **is** what will make your life together worth living.

I did a Google search and found similar phrases using both options, although the use of the singular verb almost always appeared more frequently. Is there a correct way or can either one be used?

Answer (score 1):

**Things** is plural:

> Little things like that **are** what will make your life together worth living.

You can use singular with a different construct (although this sentence is awkward because of the word that repeats):

> **It is** little things like that that will make your life together worth living.